# react-boilerplate for development is using older libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I am looking to develop a React JS web app, using react-boilerplate for development
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

But the above boilerplate doesn't seem to be updated quite often, which boilerplate should be used for building simple web apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a simple good answer to this problem. Ideally, you should create your own boilerplate and maintain it over time, because only you will know what are your most common needs. There are no perfect boilerplates and almost every boilerplate is opinionated.

You might try to create a boilerplate for yourself from React CRA or other sources that might fit your needs in a great measure. It takes time in the beginning, but after a while you might update it every few months to make sure it is up to date and make it the starting point for all your new projects.

Sometimes a good point of inspiration would be the Yeoman Generators. Take
a look here: [Yeoman Generators](https://yeoman.io/generators/)

Answer (score 3):

[Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) is pretty much a single command setup with all the basic React boilerplate code for you from the command line.

Although as others have said, ideally you should look into setting up your own boilerplate to suit your own needs and maintain it as you best see fit.

Answer (score 1):

React-boilerplate no longer to maintain, it has some library doesn't upgrade yet. You can try this repository, same about structure and way to use.
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate-cra-template

Answer (score 1):

React-boilerplate is not being maintained. You can use [ARc](https://arc.js.org/) which is a React starter kit based on the Atomic Design methodology, while I'll suggest you use create-react-app which is strongly recommended by the community.